# Signing Visual Studio manifest with PFX fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, certificate, clickonce, pfx

I am having an issue that seems to have been discussed on several occasions, but alas no solution seems to work for me. I am running VS 2013 on VMWare (on Mac) trying to publish a ClickOnce project.

Initially, I installed certificate from Windows Explorer, chose it from Store, and then from drop down list below to get

```
    An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist
```

The error does not go away after delete / repeat cycle. It only works with my personally created PFX files (obviously, not good for deployment).

I then tried exporting, uninstalling, then installing using command line, namely

```
    certutil -importPFX -user <name.pfx> AT_SIGNATURE
```

But the problem persisted. At some it started working, but then I got the

```
    Cannot import the following key file: companyname.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_3E185446540E7F7A
```

Running

```
    sn -i <certificate.pfx> VS_KEY_XXXXXXX
```

Does not change anything.

I feel really lost here and would highly appreciate any help.